# QGuiApplication screens couldn't find newly hooked monitor

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

I have an application which supposed to detect HDMI/DisplayPort monitors dynamically, say, after the QT application started, I hooked with one new monitor (i.g. my Macbook Pro has one built-in display, and it hooked with one external monitor already, now I hook the second external monitor), the application has a refresh button basically it calls
 QGuiApplication::screens();
The system can find the second external monitor w/o problem, but the screens() always returns 2 instead of 3.
Is there any API to refresh or ask QT rescan monitors? I tried QGuiApplication::sync() and it didn't work

```
QGuiApplication::sync();
auto screens = QGuiApplication::screens();
LOG("Total screens: %d", screens.count());
```

I'm using QT 5.12.4

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve].

Comment: Above code piece is the example, pretty straight

Comment: works perfectly fine for me on manjaro linux kde. is the desktop extended to all displays?

Comment: Did you try macOS Mojave? Linux might be different.

Comment: I think this is an implementation bug/feature/whatever... in Windows it works correctly too. Looking at the source code I cannot find where, in macOS, the screen change takes place (in Windows and other platforms, it does in their respective platform plugin). Does it emit the [`QGuiApplication:screenAdded`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screenAdded) signal?

Comment: Never mind, check the displays in screenAdded signal instead of in Qt concurrent watching thread and it works